# Placing an Element to the end of the DIV

Tags: css

Please please see how my `DIV` looks here:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c69669e

This is my Code for that `DIV`:

```
 <div style="background-color:#99CCFF;white-space: nowrap">
     <hr>
     <p>
         <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Site:</span>
         Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | 
         <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Device:</span>  
         CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | 
         <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface:</span> 
         Wilmington DataCenter, DC  
         <a href="url">Print</a> 
         <hr>
     </p>
 </div>
```

What I am looking for: I want to move the Print to the end of the Layout.

Comment: What about giving it position:absolute and the right:1% or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is wrong. Try breaking that into two divs, and use css floating technique to accomplish the placement. The absolute positioning will not scale up or down in different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should put your "Print" in another div and align it on the right side. So try this:

```
<div style="background-color:#99CCFF;white-space: nowrap;">
<hr><p><div style="float: right;"><a href="url">Print</a></div><span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Site:</span> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Device:</span> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface:</span> Wilmington DataCenter, DC  <hr></p>
</div>
```